# Vanilla Forum no links working

Tags: php, .htaccess

None of the links in Vanilla forum seem to go anywhere. Its like i'm stuck on the homepage and  index.php is not picking up any of the url links.

my .htaccess file:

```
# Modified
# If you modify this file then change the above line to: # Modified
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Certain hosts may require the following line.
   # If vanilla is in a subfolder then you need to specify it after the /. 
   # (ex. You put Vanilla in /forum so change the next line to: RewriteBase /forum)

   RewriteBase /forum-new
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i'm using v2.1 of Vanilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder about your last line with a backward slash, just remove it.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*Note: This .htaccess is not only related to Vanilla. But used commonly (incl Wordpress)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately its not changed anything

Comment: Also try interchanging the conditions as `[L,QSA]`

Comment: again i'm afraid this has no effect.

Comment: OK fixed it. Turns out im using 2.1b instead of 2.1. my bad. Thanks for your help though